# jquery multi match

Tags: jquery, match

How to do a multi match in jquery? match `id = a + num + b + num` or `id = a + num + c + num`(num range from 1-99)? Thanks.

```
if($(this).attr("id").match(/^a\d{1,2}b\d{1,2}$/), $(this).attr("id").match(/^a\d{1,2}c\d{1,2}$/)) 
//only work the last match
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just put an or in your regex -

```
if($(this).attr("id").match(/^a\d{1,2}b\d{1,2}$|^a\d{1,2}c\d{1,2}$/))
```